# how to count and select a max value of the count mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this code :

```
select count(quantite) from lignescommandes  where quantite ='1' 
union
select count(quantite)  from lignescommandes   where quantite ='2' 
union
select count(quantite)  from lignescommandes  where quantite ='3' ;
```

I want to select the highest value of the table that is returned but i don't see how to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `UNION`.

You can do it in only 1 scan of the table with conditional aggregation and the function `GREATEST()`:

```
SELECT GREATEST(
         COUNT(CASE WHEN quantite ='1' THEN quantite END),
         COUNT(CASE WHEN quantite ='2' THEN quantite END),
         COUNT(CASE WHEN quantite ='3' THEN quantite END)
       ) AS max_count
FROM lignescommandes
```

or with `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT GREATEST(
         SUM(quantite ='1'),
         SUM(quantite ='2'),
         SUM(quantite ='3')
       ) AS max_count
FROM lignescommandes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(c)
from (
   select count(quantite) as c from lignescommandes  where quantite ='1' 
   union
   select count(quantite)  from lignescommandes   where quantite ='2' 
   union
   select count(quantite)  from lignescommandes  where quantite ='3' 
   ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select count(*)
from lignescommandes
where quantite in ('1', '2', '3')
group by quantite
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

In other words, you are basically replicating an aggregation query with `union` which seems silly.

Also, if `quantite` (as its name implies) is a number, then drop the single quotes.  Don't mix numbers and strings.

And, if the only three values are `1`, `2`, and `3`, the `where` clause is not needed at all.